# React Native animation, render error: Invalid transform scaleDisliked: { "scaleDisliked":1 }

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

in my react native app I want to apply a transform:scale to an Animated.View component, I'm using interpolate for this effect but I'm getting the following error:

```
Render error: Invalid transform scaleDisliked: { "scaleDisliked":1 }
```

My complete code:

```
const animationDisliked = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const inputRangeDisliked = [0, 1];
  const outputRangeDisliked = [1, 0.8];
  
  //const scaleDisliked = animationDisliked.interpolate({inputRangeDisliked, outputRangeDisliked});

  const scaleDisliked = animationDisliked.interpolate({inputRange: inputRangeDisliked, outputRange: outputRangeDisliked});


<Animated.View  style={{ transform: [{scaleDisliked}],elevation:10,position:'absolute',right:10,width:95,height:95,borderRadius:95/2,backgroundColor:'white' }}>
                
                </Animated.View>
```

Any idea why I'm getting this eror?

Answer (score 0):

The object in the transform list is missing the transform key, specifically:

```js
<Animated.View
  style={{
    transform = [
      {
        scale: scaleDisliked
      }
    ],
    // ...
  }}>
</Animated.View>
```